# Is this notation correct in Database Design ERD?

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I'm creating an ERD and in this m:n relationship I'm trying to indicate that there is a composite key in the LOCATION entity (by combining Location_ID and Department_ID). I realise that this will involve a joining table when it comes to creating a table relationship diagram, but in the ERD, is this notation correct to indicate a composite key?

[image: Click to view image]

Answer (score 0):

Your PK,FK demonstration is technically not wrong but for an ERD you ultimately want to remove all many to many relationships otherwise it will cause you more problems down the line. You especially want to remove relationships like this if you have a composite key.

Here's a quick example of how i would do it roughly. (i could do a better one if i understood more info on your scenario and other tables etc...)

[image]

You ideally want to create another entity which holds both primary keys from the other tables and therefore creates a composite key. Notice, this also removes the many to many relationships.

I hope this gives you more of an understanding :)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! But I thought that instead of creating another entity, you'd use a join table (which isn't an entity to my understanding)? Therefore, you'd show this on a table relationship diagram (TRD) rather than the ERD?

Comment: @MathsHelp I have always been taught this way when it comes to composite keys and displaying them in ERD's. I think the more important thing is you want to remove the many to many relationships which is easily done by creating another entity. Otherwise if you start joining on that you could end up with very inconsistent data. However, i would be interested in seeing what you have :) If my answers has been helpful please upvote and tick the answer. Thanks :)